# Highcharts does not show zero temperature readings

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) and when rendering a temperature chart, with zero as a value for the `yAxis` temperature (being also the current chart minimum reading on the selected time scope), the chart does not show any dots or lines.

This behaviour continues until the temperature reading is 0.1 Celcius amd after that all the `yAxis` readings are displayed on the chart correctly and the dots and the line appears.

Is there a parameter to adjust this behaviour so that the zero values will always be printed on the graph?

I have tried to adjust `yAxis` padding and `minvalue` parameters but this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: https://p.dnaip.fi/2YntqQsisjY5BVIw

Comment: The data is pulled from rrdtool database to the "series[]"

Comment: Please add exemplary data set: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lp4e46g/

With some random data it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lp4e46g/1/

Comment: Actually the configuration seems to be like mine but still the zero readings are missing after the first zero appears to x-axel (7:20 first zero reading): https://oatel.net/share/no-zero-readings.JPG